# How to create a stacked column chart in SSRS 2008 out of the following data result

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, stacked-area-chart

Im facing the problem that i am not able to get the chart like the customers wants to have it.  
The chart has to look like the following:
[image]

 One column is always 100% - the 100% is the result of the good parts value plus the fail parts value. The blue area is showing the amount of good parts in percent and the area with the different different muster is the amount of fail parts in %. Each muster of the fail part area stands for a different error code.
At the moment i developed an sql statement which returns the following data 
[image]
I get the percentage amount of the good parts by calculating "Good Parts" / (divide) "Started Parts". The area of the fail parts is the sum of the "Fail parts %" column. So the sum of the two results is ~100%
As you can see in the data result a order, in this case 80383805, has four error codes (0520, 0800, 0910, 0915). What i now need is to show each error code stacked onto the amount of good parts in the chart. So far i found no workaround for that. The only thing ive created so far ist to sow two areas stacked, one with the good parts and one with the fail parts. The next step is to split the area of the fail parts into each error code. Does somebody know who to get this thing done? Thanks!

---

Thanks that helped, but now i've got another problem.
  The sorting seems not to work proper - see the following image:
[image]
 As you should see the sorting of the error codes does not seem to work. For example the second column from left. The red and the grey area should be before the orange area and not the other way round. The sql statement returns the correct sorting: 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query that returns the following:

```
Order             ErrorCode           NumberOfParts
AAAA              04858               10
AAAA              03423               25
AAAA              01234               4
AAAA              00000               100
BBBB              04858               11
BBBB              03333               22
BBBB              00000               140
CCCC              04858               28
CCCC              00000               75
```

The ErrorCode '00000' means `NoError`.

Then on SSRS, create a **100% Stacked Column** chart, and put the **ErrorCode** column on the Series Groups, the **Order** column on the Category Groups and the **NumberOfParts** on the Values.